# Are there ASCII-only image files?

Tags: image, utf-8, ascii, binaryfiles

I need some sample image data that consists of ASCII (or maybe UTF-8) characters only, with a license suitable for commercial use (in documentation).

Data should ideally be printable and unambiguous (i.e. no control chars, no tab, but space 0x20 would be ok).

Do you have any or know of any links?

Can be JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP, TIF.

Something similar to the EICAR antivirus test file that is a valid executable made up of printable ASCII characters only.

Comment: Can you use PBM, PGM or PPM (in ASCII mode)? :-) Looking at [this list of formats](http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html) you don't have a lot to choose from (as most formats contains non-ASCII characters already in their header).

Comment: Thanks, @haraldK, looks like uncompressed or RLE BMP could be possible, GIF maybe. I'd rather have one of the "popular" binary formats for Windows and the web (i.e. not SVG).

Comment: Not sure I understand how you think you can get a JPEG without non-ASCII characters but you can convert one to ASCII art with `jp2a` if that's what you mean.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, well, haven't taken a look at the fact that JPEG has binary non-ASCII data by definition. No, I don't want to convert ASCII art but a file that is printable (by extension, a UTF-8-only printable file would also do) but would be a valid image if the octets were interpreted as such.

Comment: What about base64 encoding the image - would that worlk for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Netpbm format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) is exactly that, an image format made entirely of printable characters.

The example in that Wikipedia article shows a single-bit image:

```
P1
# This is an example bitmap of the letter "J"
6 10
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This includes the magic number, dimensions and the pixel data, all expressed in ASCII.

The other file formats you suggest all require non-printable characters, either as specific magic numbers or to express any reasonable image.

Answer (score 0):

[XPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap) is also a ASCII-only image file format.

It has several variants: XPM1 and XPM3 can be emdedded directly in C programs.

Sample (XPM3):

```
/* XPM */
static char * plaid[] = {
/* plaid pixmap 
 * width height ncolors chars_per_pixel */
"22 22 5 2",
/* colors */
".  c red       m white  s light_color ",
"Y  c green     m black  s lines_in_mix ",
"+  c yellow    m white  s lines_in_dark ",
"x              m black  s dark_color ",
"   c none               s mask ",
/* pixels */
"                      x x x x x + x x x x x ", 
"                    . x x x x x x x x x x x ", 
"                  . x x x x x x + x x x x x ", 
"                . x . x x x x x x x x x x x ", 
"              . x . x x x x x x + x x x x x ", 
"            Y Y Y Y Y + x + x + x + x + x + ", 
"          x x . x . x x x x x x + x x x x x ", 
"        . x . x . x . x x x x x x x x x x x ", 
"      . x x x . x . x x x x x x + x x x x x ", 
"    . x . x . x . x . x x x x x x x x x x x ", 
"  . x . x x x . x . x x x x x x + x x x x x ", 
". . . . . x . . . . . x . x . x Y x . x . x ", 
". . . . . x . . . . . . x . x . Y . x . x . ",
". . . . . x . . . . . x . x . x Y x . x . x ", 
". . . . . x . . . . . . x . x . Y . x . x . ", 
". . . . . x . . . . . x . x . x Y x . x . x ", 
"x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x ", 
". . . . . x . . . . . x . x . x Y x . x . x ", 
". . . . . x . . . . . . x . x . Y . x . x . ", 
". . . . . x . . . . . x . x . x Y x . x . x ", 
". . . . . x . . . . . . x . x . Y . x . x . ", 
". . . . . x . . . . . x . x . x Y x . x . x "
} ;
```

XPM2 has a more concise syntax:

```
! XPM2
48 4 2 1
a c #FFFFFF
b c #000000
abaabaababaaabaabababaabaabaababaabaaababaabaaab
abaabaababaaabaabababaabaabaababaabaaababaabaaab
abaabaababaaabaabababaabaabaababaabaaababaabaaab
abaabaababaaabaabababaabaabaababaabaaababaabaaab
```